# Recursive definition of a sum of squares

Tags: lean3, recursion

I am trying to formalise in `Lean3` the notion of sum of squares in a ring.

If $ A $ is a ring, $ n $ is an integer and $ f $ is a function from $$ F_n:= \{ i \in \mathbb{N} \ |\ 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n \}$$ to $ A $, then

$$ 
\sum_{i = 1}^n f(i)^2 := \left\{ 
\begin{array}{cl}
0 & \text{if } n = 0 \\
\sum_{ i = 0 }^{ k } f(i)^2 + f( k + 1 )^2 & \text{if } n = \mathrm{succ}(k)
\end{array} 
\right.
$$

according to whether $ n $ is $ 0 $ or the successor of an integer.

> I am using $f: F_n \to A$ as a way to list $n$ elements $ a_i := f(i) $ in $A$.

However, I have not been able to write it down properly like that. I would like to eventually reach something like this

```
def sum_of_squares {A : Ring} (n : nat) : (range n → A.dom) → A.dom
```

in which, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, `sum_of_squares n` is a function that takes a function $ f : F_n \to A $ to the element $ \sum_{i=0}^n f(i)^2 \in A$.

> Here `range n` (defined in `Lean`as the set of natural numbers less than $n$) represents the set $F_n$ introduced above.

And I would like to define this recursively by using induction on $ n $:

- If $ n = 0 $, then `sum_of_squares n := λ f, 0`. Or in other words, for all $f : F_n \to A$, `sum_of_squares 0 f := 0`.
- If $ n = \mathrm{succ}(k) $, then `sum_of_squares n := λ f, (sum_of_squares k f) + f(k+1)^2`.

But I have not been able to do it. I wonder if this is a problem with the code or if there is a theoretical oversight on my part with this definition.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :-)

***Edit (with code for failed attempt):*** My issue with the code is that I am unable to formalise the distinction between $ n = 0 $ and $ n = \mathrm{succ}(k)$ that I introduced above. I think it should go something like this:

```
def sum_of_squares {A : Ring} (n : nat) : (range n → A.dom) → A.dom 
| λ f, 0
| λ f, (sum_of_squares k f) + ((f (k+1) ) * (f (k+1) ))
```

but then `Lean`returns the message `invalid expression starting at 3:0`. I am wondering if this is a syntax problem or is there in fact no chance of making this work.

I thought that the problem might come from my use of `range n`, so I tried to modify the definition to

```
def sum_of_squares {A : Ring} (n : nat) : (nat → A.dom) → A.dom
```

but I get the same error message.

In case it is useful, let me add that `nat` is just the usual type of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ as implemented in `Lean3`, and that `Ring` is a class that I would like to be defined like this:

```
class Ring := mk_Ring ::
(dom : Type)
(sum : dom → dom → dom)
(prod : dom → dom → dom)
(zero : dom)
(one : dom)
-- + axioms of a ring
```

In the code above, I have used `+` and `*` instead of `A.sum` and `A.prod`, for the sake of clarity.

I am preparing this for an exercise session in a formalisation seminar, in which one of the goals is to manipulate basic definitions, not necessarily use the full power of `mathlib`. But of course I am interested in all comment or advice that you may have  Thanks!

***Edit 2:*** The following definition seems to be accepted by `Lean3`:

```
def sum_of_squares {A : my_ring} (f : nat → A.dom) : nat → A.dom
| 0 := A.zero
| (n+1) := (sum_of_squares n) + ((f n) * (f n))
```

I do not know how to make this approach work for `f: range n  → A.dom`, though.

Basically, what I want is a `for` loop: given a list $(a_0, ... , a_{n-1})$ of $ n $ elements of $ A $, I want to define the sum $ \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i^2$ recursively, starting from `sum = 0` if $n=0$ and then by returning the value at the end of the following loop:

```
for i in range n: 
         sum = sum + a[i]^2,
         i = i + 1
```

I have found the following post by [Mario Carneiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/890016/mario-carneiro) about `for` loops in `Lean`, but I have not been able to use it yet:

> [Loops in Lean programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70871764/22005810)

Comment: Can you show some (possibly failed) code attempts? Otherwise we wouldn't know whether it is a problem with the code.

Comment: @Trebor Hi! Just added the code for my failed attempt :-) I hope that this clarifies what my issue is. Thanks!

Comment: I’m confused why your informal  definition is well-defined.  $f$ depends on $n$, so let’s explicitly write it $f_n$.  Your partial sum up to $k$ in the recurrent definition is using  $f_k$ or $f_n$?  I think when you can write this down explicitly in math notation using all the indices you with then know how to formalize it.

Comment: You are right to first try with `nat` in place of `range n`.  You are using the wrong syntax for a recursive definition in Lean 3.  I would look again at Theorem Proving in Lean for examples of the correct syntax.

Comment: Finally I would write your informal definition using $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}$.  It would better align with the fact that in Lean natural numbers start with 0.

Comment: @JasonRute Yes, I was indeed finally able to write a recursive definition with `nat` in place of `range n`. I will edit the post now, to explain better where I am at now.

Comment: Also I think you need to use `fin n` in place of `range n`.  The former is a type with exactly n elements.  The later is (I think) just a list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually tried `fin n` at first, then switched to `range n`. But I should re-examine it, now that I have a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: Sorry for my last comment.  Ignore that.  `range n` seems fine as it returns a `finsum nat`.  Also I dont know if you want to code this from scratch, but note this is already in mathlib.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69689347/how-to-use-the-summation-sign-in-lean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there some reason you don't like the straightforward definition?

```
def sum_list_squares : List Nat → Nat
  | [] => 0
  | a :: lst => a * a + sum_list_squares lst
```

This is easily generalized to replace `Nat` with an arbitrary `A` that has addition.

Comment: That's exactly what I was hoping for but was not able to write myself, thank you so much :-) And yes, no problem generalizing it to `A` that is not necessarily `Nat`.